Where are the critical points of a proper faithfully flat morphism
Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are compact complex manifolds and $f:X\to Y$ is a faithfully flat map. This map will generally not be a submersion, but it is a submersion away from singular fibres. Assuming that the singular fibres of $f$ are relatively tame (e.g. they form a normal crossing divisor in $X$), can we say anything about where critical points would be located in the singular fibres?
The naive thought is that the critical points should lie in the singular loci of the singular fibres, but does anyone know of any results that could back up that intuition?

In the algebraic category, your intuition is made precise by this result:  https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01V8.

@DoriBejleri the result you mention only implies that critical points will be contained in singular fibres. My question is about where we should expect the critical points to be within a singular fibre. (Do critical points only appear at singular points of the singular fibres, or can they appear anywhere within a singular fibre?)

@EricBoulter I think you want the equivalence of (1) and (2) here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01V9

Take a point $x \in X$ and set $y = f(x)  \in Y$. Let $X_y = f^{-1}(y)$ the "scheme-theoretic" fiber, i.e. the complex-analytic subspace of $X$ which is cut out the equation $f(x) = y$. Your question is local in $X$, so choose complex coordinates $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$ around $x$ and $y_1, \dotsc, y_m$ around $y$. Then both assertions

$x$ a regular point of $f$,
$X_y$ is smooth at $x$,

are equivalent to

the differential matrix $Df(x) = \left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x)\right)_{ij}$ has full rank.

So yes, a point $x$ is critical if and only if the fiber is singular at $x$.
